# Count number of objects using watershed algorithm - Scikit-image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, scikit-image, watershed

I am trying to find the number of objects in a given image using watershed segmentation. Consider for example the [coins image](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/_images/water_coins.jpg). Here I would like to know the number of coins in the image. I implemented the code available at [Scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_watershed.html) documentation and tweaked with it a little and got results similar to those displayed on the documentation page.

After looking at functions used in the code in detail I found out that ndimage.label() also returns number of unique objects found in the image (mentioned in it's documentation), but when I print that value I am getting 53 which is very high as compared to the number of coins in the actual image.

Can somebody suggest some method to find the number of objects in an image.

Comment: Can you please provide an example image?

Comment: I have attached the link for the input image in the question itself. The final result is available at  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxL8fZVtRVZPbldJUzVKazVmSlk/view?usp=sharing). Here is code [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxL8fZVtRVZPbFFRbGczdzdGRzg/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version of your code that counts the coins in one of two ways: a) by directly segmenting the distance image and b) by doing watershed first and rejecting tiny intersecting regions.

```py
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io, color, filter as filters
from scipy import ndimage

from skimage.morphology import watershed
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage.measure import regionprops, label

image = color.rgb2gray(io.imread('water_coins.jpg', plugin='freeimage'))
image = image < filters.threshold_otsu(image)

distance = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(image)

# Here's one way to measure the number of coins directly
# from the distance map
coin_centres = (distance > 0.8 * distance.max())
print('Number of coins (method 1):', np.max(label(coin_centres)))

# Or you can proceed with the watershed labeling
local_maxi = peak_local_max(distance, indices=False, footprint=np.ones((3, 3)),
                            labels=image)


markers, num_features = ndimage.label(local_maxi)
labels = watershed(-distance, markers, mask=image)

# ...but then you have to clean up the tiny intersections between coins
regions = regionprops(labels)
regions = [r for r in regions if r.area > 50]

print('Number of coins (method 2):', len(regions) - 1)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(8, 2.7))
ax0, ax1, ax2 = axes

ax0.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
ax0.set_title('Overlapping objects')
ax1.imshow(-distance, cmap=plt.cm.jet, interpolation='nearest')
ax1.set_title('Distances')
ax2.imshow(labels, cmap=plt.cm.spectral, interpolation='nearest')
ax2.set_title('Separated objects')

for ax in axes:
    ax.axis('off')

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.01, wspace=0.01, top=1, bottom=0, left=0,
                    right=1)
plt.show()
```